# Simple Spring Security requirement

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have read the doc from http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-minimal

I don't need role here and I don't need any databases. This document is too much for my requirement. I just want to authenticate a user via a login page.After the user is successfully authenticated, I will create a cookie. All coming request will be checked whether they have a valid cookie.

My ideas:  there will be a filter checking each coming request and a entry point redirect the user to the login page if the cookie expires.

But I have no idea of integrating these simple requirement with spring security... or should I use something else ?

Comment: And how are you authenticating? Where aer you storing youer users? You need somehwere to store yuor username/password combo's. You also don't need roles that is an option not a requirement...

Comment: @JobSmith Can you use Spring Boot in your project? If so, what you are asking for can be implemented with a lot less configuration

Comment: @M. Deinum I will use an API to authenticate the credentials.

Comment: Then simply provide your own `UserDetailsService` or `AuthenticationProvider` which wraps this API.

Comment: @M. Deinum thanks Deinum,I got confused. could you come up with sample xml configuration? thanks again..

Comment: If i do it in an old java way, I will simply extend filter class and in the filter i check the cookie...but with sprint security..i am lost..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java Config then you Spring Security Configuration would look like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private YourSpecificProvider provider; //simply wraps your API calls

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/fonts/**", "/images/**").permitAll() //add whatever else needs to be served without authentication
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
    }
}
```

With that setup, Spring Security will automatically handle all the necessary steps to add the cookie/check the cookie/redirect/etc.
You would of course have to provide a login page at `/login`

Depending on how you are using Spring, you will need to add Spring Security to the Servlet Filter Chain

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be accomplished using Spring Security with minimal configuration.
Since you don't want to store user credentials in database, you can store that in the configuration itself in encoded format (though
this is something no one should suggest you because of security reasons - but that's another topic)
What you are trying to do via a cookie is similar to "remember me" functionality provided by Spring out of the box.
To do all this you typically need to put a filter declaration / mapping and a minimal configuration file in place and login/logout page and you are done.
You can take a look at simple example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/).
If later you require more (you never know :-)) you already have a rock solid product.

Comment: thanks Shailendra, actually I won't store the username/password anywhere. Once I know the username/password matches(could be an api call), I generate a cookie.

Comment: Then you can plugin the appropriate UserDetailService into the configuration very easily.

Answer (score 0):

Spring security after validate a user create on the session(cookie) the Authentication object that is added into the SecurityContextHolder.

First of all you need to create the Authentication manager

```
  public class RestAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {


   @Override
   public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    RestToken restToken = (RestToken) authentication;

    String key = restToken.getKey();
    String credentials = restToken.getCredentials();

    User user = //Here create the implementation of how to validate the user


    if(user == null){
        throw new BadCredentialsException("User does not exist");
    }
    authentication = getAuthenticatedUser(user);
    ((RestToken) authentication).setDetails(user);
    return authentication;
}


private Authentication getAuthenticatedUser(User user) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole()));
    return new RestToken(user.getId(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
}

@Override
/*
    Determines if this class can support the token provided by the filter.
 */
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return RestToken.class.equals(authentication);
}
```

}

And then when you receive the login from the page invoke that authentication manager and save the Authentication object created.

```
               Authentication successfulAuthentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(successfulAuthentication);
```